# HERE Maps Javascript API - Throwing "Pointer Must Have ID" Error

Tags: javascript, here-api

I'm just getting started with the HERE API.  I've copied the example from the JavaScript quick start that can plot map points based on user entered location strings.  That works great.

However, if I touch or click the map I get the error "Pointer must have ID" raised in here map events JS. I can't see any element difference between my code and the example - nor any reference to map touch handling.  I'm assuming there's a missing wireup of the touch or click event raised ... just wondering if anyone has a quick suggestion.

To be clear: This map is being rendered in Cordova web view...

I'm going back to API to look and will post whatever I find in case I figure it out.

Thanks,
Dave Gerding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the delayed answer.  The problem was not Cordvoa/Telerik AppBuilder but the device simulator.  As soon as I ran on a real device / "real" emulator the problem went away.  To be clear: Telerik AppBuilder's device simulator was the problem.  It's a browser-based simulator to host a web view rather than a real device dependent web view control running a native platform.  Works well most of the time - but not this one.

Answer (score 0):

Which platform for cordova are you testing on ? Tried on android and seems to work fine. On a side note HERE does provide a SDK of their which might be more optimal for mobile devices.

Documentation is available on the following link
https://developer.here.com/documentation